# Get a sum of specific cells under condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm convinced that what I want to do is obvious, but I've been stuck on it for an hour.

Here is a simplified version of my database:

```
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
|  EXERCICE  |   MCOT  |  MCOT_1  |  MCOT_2 |
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
|       2016 | 1754.00 |  1385.00 |  776.00 |
|       2016 | 3166.00 | 14291.00 |  582.00 |
|       2015 | 1385.00 |     0.00 | 5820.00 |
|       2016 |    0.00 |  4551.00 | 5969.00 |
|       2014 |  792.00 |  3364.00 | 2522.00 |
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

All I'm trying to do is to be able to sum in a way or another of each columns (MCOT, MCOT_1, MCOT_2) together as long as the exercice year is the same

My desired output is the following:

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+
|  max_year  |   last_year  |  year_before  |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
|   32474    |     7205     |     6678      |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I tried a few things like

```
SELECT MCOT + MCOT_1 + MCOT_2 AS max_year WHERE EXERCICE = MAX(EXERCICE) FROM TABLE
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN EXERCICE = MAX(EXERCICE) THEN MCOT + MCOT_1 + MCOT_2 END) 
AS max_year FROM table
```

I guess I'm doing this terribly but I thought it would be easier than this.

How should I do this?

Comment: A smarter solution would be to fix your schema design.

Comment: Man I wish I could...

Comment: Well, you can emulate it with a series of UNIONS.

Comment: This isn't my own datas but the client's, plus this is a Drupal environment, so the less I touch it, the more I keep my will to live

Comment: There is no sense in which UNIONS 'touch' an environment any more than any other kind of SELECT clause. I'm not sure what the fact that it's Drupal has to do with the price of fish. I appreciate that it's not your mess, but I suspect that there are better ways of cleaning it up than the answer provided below.

Comment: Presumably, there's a PRIMARY KEY somewhere, which you've omitted?

Comment: No there's not, it's like a huge database dump with implicit column name, raw datas and stuff. Fortunately it doesn't take much time figure out what's the point of all this, but this is far from "clean"

Comment: OK - Although I'm a little surprised that Drupal maintains no referential integrity

Comment: I don't believe Drupal is used to do this, but I won't be able to tell you how they did their dump, but I'd say some obscure SQL sofwares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `SELECT`, `FROM`, `TABLE` and then the `WHERE` condition, and in order to get sum of columns, you should use `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(MCOT + MCOT_1 + MCOT_2) AS Total
FROM your_table
WHERE EXERCICE = (SELECT MAX(EXERCISE) AS EXERCISE FROM your_table);
```

Comment: I get `Syntax error near 'WHEN EXERCICE = MAX(EXERCICE)' at line 3`

Comment: Hmm, got it. We need to SELECT the `MAX(EXERCISE)` and use it in the query. Have updated the query.

Comment: There is still a syntax error, on line 3, but it's around `WHEN EXERCICE =` (sorry I can't help more)

Comment: Oops, its `WHERE` and not `WHEN`

Comment: It worked! Thank you a lot, now I guess i wouldn't have find it by myself..

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [up-vote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)